# Combining multiple piecharts into one figure with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

I need to combine 4 pie charts (code below) into one figure with one combined legend. I've tried several different codes, but because not all of the piecharts share the same categories, I'm having issues combining them. Has anyone run into this issue before? How can I combine these into one figure with a shared legend that contains all of the categories? Thanks!

```
#plot 1
Traits <- c("Respiratory diseases 23.05%", "Thyroid diseases 5.47%", "Anthropometric measurements 19.14%", "White blood cell counts 7.81%", "Diabetes 10.16%", "Cognitive and education related traits 7.81%", "Ocular traits 8.98%", "Other traits 17.58%")
counts <- c(59,14,49,20,26,20,23,45)
labels <- c("23.05%", "5.47%", "19.14%", "7.81%", "10.16%", "7.81%", "8.98%", "17.58%")
df <- data.frame(Traits, counts)

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(csum = rev(cumsum(rev(counts))), 
         pos = counts/2 + lead(csum, 1),
         pos = if_else(is.na(pos), counts/2, pos)) 

ggplot(df, aes(x="", y= counts, fill = fct_inorder(Traits))) +
  geom_col(width = 1, color = 1) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Pastel2") +
  ggtitle(expression(paste("Significant associations with", italic(" GDF11" ), " in OpenTarget Genetics"))) +
  geom_label_repel(data = df2, aes(y = pos, label = labels), size = 4.5, nudge_x = 1, show.legend = FALSE) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Traits")) +
  theme_void() 

#plot 2
Traits <- c("Respiratory diseases 16.48%", "Thyroid diseases 2.20%", "Anthropometric measurements 14.29%", "White blood cell counts 2.20%", "Cognitive and education related traits 7.69%", "Cardiovascular traits 5.49%", "Psychiatric traits 12.09%", "Other traits 12.09%")
counts <- c(15, 2, 13, 2, 7, 5, 11, 11)
labels <- c("16.48%", "2.20%", "14.29%", "2.20%", "7.69%", "5.49%", "12.09%", "12.09%")
df <- data.frame(Traits, counts)

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(csum = rev(cumsum(rev(counts))), 
         pos = counts/2 + lead(csum, 1),
         pos = if_else(is.na(pos), counts/2, pos)) 

ggplot(df, aes(x="", y= counts, fill = fct_inorder(Traits))) +
  geom_col(width = 1, color = 1) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Pastel2") +
  ggtitle(expression(paste("Significant associations with", italic(" GDF11" ), " in TWAS Hub"))) +
  geom_label_repel(data = df2, aes(y = pos, label = labels), size = 4.5, nudge_x = 1, show.legend = FALSE) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Traits")) +
  theme_void() 

#plot 3
Traits <- c("Red blood cell traits 56.36%", "Platelet counts 10.91%", "Mineral levels/content 10.91%", "Other 21.82%")
counts <- c(31, 6, 6, 12)
labels <- c("56.36%", "10.91%", "10.91%", "21.82%")
df <- data.frame(Traits, counts)

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(csum = rev(cumsum(rev(counts))), 
         pos = counts/2 + lead(csum, 1),
         pos = if_else(is.na(pos), counts/2, pos)) 

ggplot(df, aes(x="", y= counts, fill = fct_inorder(Traits))) +
  geom_col(width = 1, color = 1) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Pastel2") +
  ggtitle(expression(paste("Significant associations with", italic(" MSTN" ), " in OpenTarget Genetics"))) +
  geom_label_repel(data = df2, aes(y = pos, label = labels), size = 4.5, nudge_x = 1, show.legend = FALSE) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Traits")) +
  theme_void() 

#plot 4
Traits <- c("Cardiovascular traits 21.88%", "Respiratory traits 31.25%", "Thyroid disease 6.25%", "Anthropometrics 18.75%", "Other 21.88%")
counts <- c(7, 10, 2, 6, 7)
labels <- c("21.88%", "31.25%", "6.25%", "18.75%", "21.88%")
df <- data.frame(Traits, counts)

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(csum = rev(cumsum(rev(counts))), 
         pos = counts/2 + lead(csum, 1),
         pos = if_else(is.na(pos), counts/2, pos)) 

ggplot(df, aes(x="", y= counts, fill = fct_inorder(Traits))) +
  geom_col(width = 1, color = 1) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Pastel2") +
  ggtitle(expression(paste("Significant associations with", italic(" MSTN" ), " in TWAS Hub"))) +
  geom_label_repel(data = df2, aes(y = pos, label = labels), size = 4.5, nudge_x = 1, show.legend = FALSE) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Traits")) +
  theme_void()
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create your four pie charts using faceting. To this end put your four dfs in one using e.g. `dplyr::bind_rows` and add an identifier which could be used for faceting. Doing so you could simplify your code considerably. The important steps IMHO are that I converted your counts to percentages so the values for each pie sum up to 1. Also I added an `order` column which could be mapped on the `group` aes to make sure that the labels are in the right position. Also, I removed the percentages from `Traits` to reduce the number of categories to be displayed in the legend. And use `ggtext::element_markdown` to format part of the "titles" in italics. Still IMHO this is not perfect, especially with the large number of categories and colors. Personally I would simply choose a bar chart instead of using pies. But it's your plot. (;

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(forcats)

df_all <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4) %>%
  lapply(function(x) mutate(x, order = row_number())) |>
  bind_rows(.id = "id") %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(order) |>
  mutate(
    counts = counts / sum(counts),
    csum = rev(cumsum(rev(counts))),
    pos = counts / 2 + lead(csum, 1),
    pos = if_else(is.na(pos), counts / 2, pos)
  ) |>
  mutate(Traits = gsub("\\s\\d+\\.\\d+%$", "", Traits))

facet_labels <- c(
  "*GDF11* in OpenTarget Genetics",
  "*GDF11* in TWAS Hub",
  "*MSTN* in OpenTarget Genetics",
  "*MSTN* in TWAS Hub"
)
names(facet_labels) <- 1:4

pal_fill <- scales::brewer_pal(palette = "Pastel2")(8)
pal_fill <- colorRampPalette(pal)(n_distinct(df_all$Traits))

ggplot(df_all, aes(x = "", y = counts, fill = Traits, group = order)) +
  geom_col(width = 1, color = 1) +
  geom_label_repel(aes(y = pos, label = labels), nudge_x = 1, show.legend = FALSE, size = 10 / .pt) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = pal_fill) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Traits")) +
  theme_void() +
  facet_wrap(~id, labeller = labeller(id = facet_labels)) +
  labs(title = "Significant associations with ") +
  theme(strip.text.x = ggtext::element_markdown(margin = margin(t = 5.5, b = 5.5)),
        plot.title = element_text(margin = margin(t = 5.5, b = 5.5)),
        plot.margin = unit(rep(5.5, 4), "pt"))
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
# plot 1
Traits <- c("Respiratory diseases 23.05%", "Thyroid diseases 5.47%", "Anthropometric measurements 19.14%", "White blood cell counts 7.81%", "Diabetes 10.16%", "Cognitive and education related traits 7.81%", "Ocular traits 8.98%", "Other traits 17.58%")
counts <- c(59, 14, 49, 20, 26, 20, 23, 45)
labels <- c("23.05%", "5.47%", "19.14%", "7.81%", "10.16%", "7.81%", "8.98%", "17.58%")
df1 <- data.frame(Traits, counts, labels)

# plot 2
Traits <- c("Respiratory diseases 16.48%", "Thyroid diseases 2.20%", "Anthropometric measurements 14.29%", "White blood cell counts 2.20%", "Cognitive and education related traits 7.69%", "Cardiovascular traits 5.49%", "Psychiatric traits 12.09%", "Other traits 12.09%")
counts <- c(15, 2, 13, 2, 7, 5, 11, 11)
labels <- c("16.48%", "2.20%", "14.29%", "2.20%", "7.69%", "5.49%", "12.09%", "12.09%")
df2 <- data.frame(Traits, counts, labels)

# plot 3
Traits <- c("Red blood cell traits 56.36%", "Platelet counts 10.91%", "Mineral levels/content 10.91%", "Other 21.82%")
counts <- c(31, 6, 6, 12)
labels <- c("56.36%", "10.91%", "10.91%", "21.82%")
df3 <- data.frame(Traits, counts, labels)

# plot 4
Traits <- c("Cardiovascular traits 21.88%", "Respiratory traits 31.25%", "Thyroid disease 6.25%", "Anthropometrics 18.75%", "Other 21.88%")
counts <- c(7, 10, 2, 6, 7)
labels <- c("21.88%", "31.25%", "6.25%", "18.75%", "21.88%")
df4 <- data.frame(Traits, counts, labels)
```